# Can VBScript separate a string based on the first instance of a delimiter only?

Tags: vbscript

I know I can split a string into multiple substrings by giving a delimiter. I know I can also choose a substring based on character position like this:

```
sAddressOverflow = Right(sAddressLine1,5)
```

What I would like to do though is split an input string like this:

> "123 South Main Street Apt. 24B"

But I only want to end up with two substrings which are split based on the first space to the left of the 25th character.  So my desired output using the above input would be:

> Substring1 = "123 South Main Street"
>   Substring2 = "Apt. 24B"

Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible, but there's no built-in function for that. You'll have to create your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions have the advantage that you can configure your pattern independently from the location where you use it and that they are highly adaptable, so I prefer to do string manipulation with regular expressions. Unfortunately the pattern of Ansgar Wiechers does not exactly match your requirement. Here is one that does:

```
myString = "1234 6789A 234567 9B12 4567 890"
Set re = new RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(.{1,25}) (.*)$"
Set matches = re.Execute(myString)

wscript.echo "leftpart: " & matches(0).submatches(0)
wscript.echo "rightpart: " & matches(0).submatches(1)
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the *25th character* bit. However, for that requirement I'd simply use [`Mid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28v=vs.84%29) instead of messing around with a regular expression.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers well, it is actually a bit trickier: You have to split at the first space before the 25th character. Doing it with string manipulation functions you'll need `left(str,instrrev(left(str,25)," ")-1)` and `mid(str,instrrev(left(str,25))+1,len(str))`. This makes it not very easy to read and maintain. This code will also throw an error if `len(str)<25` or when there is no space in the first 25 chars. With a regexp you can simply test if `matches.count > 0` to see if the string complied to these conditions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such inbuilt function available,
but you might want to try this,

```
add = "123 South Main Street Apt. 24B"
valid = Left(add,25)
arr = Split(valid)
char= InStrRev(add,arr(UBound(arr)))-1
address1 = Left(add,char)
address2= Right(add,Len(add)-char)
Wscript.echo address1
Wscript.echo address2
```

this might not be the perfect way, but it works !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression, but you need a well defined format:

```
addr = "123 South Main Street Apt. 24B"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = "^(\d+ .*) +(apt\. +\d+(.*?))$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

Set m = re.Execute(addr)
If m.Count > 0 Then
  WScript.Echo m(0).SubMatches(0)
  WScript.Echo m(0).SubMatches(1)
End If
```

By "well-defined format" I mean that you need some "anchors" (or fix points) in your expression to identify the parts in the string. In the example the anchor is the substring "apt." followed by one or more digits.